# HTML Source code iterpretation

Tags: html

i dont quite understand how this webpage displays it's data as the source code simply shows it's google tag code.

where does the code for the page layout come from?

http://www.trademe.co.nz/property/insights/address/Auckland/Orakei/Tautari-Street/42/60e6b7b1-d472-4fe2-bab1-7b8a9c18e641

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head ng-controller="headController as ctrl">
    <base href="/">
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0,height=device-height"/>
    <meta name="description" content="Search over 1.5 million New Zealand properties and discover free estimated market values, sold prices, rateable valuations and more." />
    <meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=550943614, affiliate-data=1010lc5k"/>
    <title>House sold prices & property information | Trade Me Property Insights</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/property/insights/css/app.css?v=Xq_vVMQyeqWVriJqrsx95fOd3kQR4nYrrMxb8sLFsl4" />

    <!-- Google Tag Manager TODO add key in iFrame for production-->
    <noscript>
        <iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-WP683K>" height="0" width="0" style="display: none; visibility: hidden"></iframe>
    </noscript>

    <script>
        var testRegEx = /test[1-9][a-z]/i;
        var containerId = 'GTM-KMC2M2';
        if (/test[1-9][a-z]/i.test(window.location.origin)) containerId = 'GTM-WP683K';
        if (/.dev.trademe.co.nz/i.test(window.location.origin)) containerId = 'GTM-53CZK6';
        (function(w, d, s, l, i) {
            w[l] = w[l] || [];
            w[l].push(
                { 'gtm.start': new Date().getTime(), event: 'gtm.js' }
            );
            var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
                j = d.createElement(s),
                dl = l != 'dataLayer' ? '&l=' + l : '';
            j.async = true;
            j.src =
                '//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=' + i + dl;
            f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);
        })(window, document, 'script', 'dataLayer', containerId);
    </script>


<link href="/property/insights/styles.0f79228bbfea7a89f25f.bundle.css?v=qL0UK5rKQQTni727hQPz_P9WxK7qhDCkpkC3fzJ_Kuk" rel="stylesheet" /></head>
<body>

<input id="HostingEnvironment" name="HostingEnvironment" type="hidden" value="Production" />

<app>
    <div class="loading-container">
        <img src="/property/insights/images/loader.svg" />
        <div class="loading-text">Just a moment...</div>
    </div>
</app>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/property/insights/inline.9119e57f92f5676e8860.bundle.js?v=Ef2IUZ--xAfHSZwkaFyNspZ7PkjVfBAh8gQYGNLYbKc"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/property/insights/polyfills.6292e3ee5e1ea889726b.bundle.js?v=ryy3leF6QDbqOPfS7dyHC0QD_QKX5vjwiNit2pfnyAU"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/property/insights/vendor.d418eda2f891d23557f3.bundle.js?v=t7foCzMb9MYsSguXz23JEwECvn_9RDoKaJIfSpijuAs"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/property/insights/main.54e60317a2b1ac8487cb.bundle.js?v=wqYIDaveFz1-mbQA_o01prc5-eoXnyOH9x83fK2gSFw"></script></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a bunch of script tags at the end of the page - these are all likely the scripts that load the application - layout and all.